# store and reuse crossfilter object

Tags: dc.js

I am planning to generate a dc js crossfilter object in one page and use it across multiple pages; is there a way to serialise and store the crossfilter object in local storage and reuse it?

Thanks,
Arun

Comment: No, crossfilter has no serialization and you can't store live objects in local storage. If your data is not huge I'd suggest putting the data in local storage and recreate the crossfilter objects using some shared code.

Comment: Alright, thanks Gordon!!